# unable to display map

Tags: android, google-maps

Trying to display simple map in my emulator/real device.

I have also get the key from google, put the google service library in my workspace etc..

here is the code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);      
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
    }
    }
```

[image]

The above output I am getting..I dont know what I am missing..Any help is appriciate

Thanks.

Comment: Any error/warning in the logcat?

Comment: do you have configured the api key on your pc?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this situation is a debug key issue. 
First of all you have to generate a certificate with [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)
 The location of the keystore varies by platform:

> Windows Vista: C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore
>
> Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\.android\debug.keystore
>
> OS X and Linux: ~/.android/debug.keystore

When you have generated the certificate, you have to use the

> [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)

command to get the MD5 fingerprint of the debug certificate. You can achieve this by running something like

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and you will get an output something like :

```
androiddebugkey, Apr 2, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 72:BF:25:C1:AF:4C:C1:2F:34:D9:B1:90:35:XX:XX:XX
```

You have to use this finger print  in Google Maps service in google apis console.
For further details, you can see the [official google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key)

Comment: Hi,Yes I have already get key from google and using it. after that I am getting this error.

Comment: Is the package name that you have declared in google api the same in the package name in the manifest?